# For SEO, should I integrate iFrame google maps within noscript if I load the map dynamicly?

Tags: seo, javascript

Hey I use javascript with the IntersectionObserver to load google map API when the user scroll down to the bottom of the page (where my map div is at).

I was wondering if I need to add an iFrame at the same spot of the page, but within noscript tag, just for SEO purpose, so that google actually knows that I'm using their maps.

I'm seeing conflictual informations about this over the web, some say it's not important since google now crawls through javascript. But isn't it a safety net ?

Comment: "so that google actually knows that I'm using their maps"  -- How would Google knowing that you are using their maps help with SEO?   They aren't going to rank your page better just because it has a map in it.   Nor do maps contain keywords that you need to get indexed in your page.

Comment: I thought including the GMaps api and locating my buisness with my specific business id would help rank the business a tad bit higher in google maps. I'm probably confusing things :p

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with local SEO, but I doubt that having Google maps on your site is going to influence your rankings at all.    It isn't in one of the top 20 local SEO factors according to Moz: https://moz.com/blog/top-20-local-search-ranking-factors-an-illustrated-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run an A/B test with fetch and render and mobile friendly test.

Try out the javascript and iframe versions in both. You can use fetch and render in Search Console as well as Google's mobile friendly test to determine if Google is able to render the map with both versions.

If Google is able to render one version and not the other, I would be likely to use the version that it can render unless there is a truly compelling reason to use the other.